# MS Access form not displaying data from the tables

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm building a new Access 2007 database with a large number of tables. Designed a form with multiple tabs to display the fields from various tables, which all have a relationship with each other. When new data is entered it is all being saved correctly to the various tables. However, when the form is opened it is not displaying any of the data stored in the tables. The form properties seem to be set correctly, it allows additions and editing and is not set for data entry only. Running the query that is the recordsource fails to return any records, which looks like the problem lies there, and yet the recordsource must be correct if it is able to save the new data entered to the right tables. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: Is the form bound? If not, which event is used to populate the form? In either case, what is the SQL statement?

Comment: @Remou: Can't give SQL statement, too long. All fields on form bound to their respective tables. Form data property has an On Loan setting which is blank, but it's also blank on one of my other forms and the data displays on it automatically.

Comment: There is a difference between the controls being bound and the form itself being bound. Is the record source for the form set to this really long sql statement? BTW a really long sql statement is not a particularly good sign.

Answer (score 1):

Check you database connection If database connection is established correctly then you need to check you database query e.g if you are writing this query

```
Select * from tableName
```

Just copy it and run in access sql query editor if that work fine it means some thing is wrong in you form data retrrvil mechanism.
Hope it helps you

Comment: Ordinary queries running fine. Record source for form though has 23 inner joins and a minimum of 158 data fields. Previous design in use had only one table for all the data, but I didn't feel that was good design, not normalised, so I split it up. Perhaps Access form is having trouble with so many joins? Although as it can save correctly the joins have to be working correctly, don't they?

Comment: @ChelleMcGaughey From the sound of it, you need guidance on the design of the database. 23 joins sounds quite a lot.

Comment: @ChelleMcGaughey first of all you need to change your database design if it is wrong onother side if your design is fine then your query will work fine as per your requirement. I worked as a database consultant and write many queries but did'nt get it any issue. If you are not much fimilar with Tsql you can use any query designer which can help you in writing query.

Comment: It was my belief that if there were a large number of data elements, they should be divided into different tables with each table specific to one subject. So for a hospital database, one table for Patient, one for Consultant, one for Surgery, one for Drugs and so on. For a user to then record data in the form, the form's record source needs to use joins to allow the data to be saved to all the individual tables. So is this not the right design to use? Surely saving all this different data into one table isn't right?